# Python/Windows: Fuzzing program from cmd

Tags: python, windows, cmd, buffer-overflow, fuzzing

I am trying to fuzz a Windows program to detect Buffer Overflow, using python to generate inputs.

My code is something like this:

```
python -c "print('A'*100)" | .\program.exe
```

Unfortunately, PIPE command seems not working like on Unix systems, because the string is not provided to the program as input. The idea is also avoiding the usage of "temp" variables.

Any idea on how to solve the issue?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The pipe should work as expected here.

Comment: Sounds like your question is more about how to pipe on Windows than about fuzzing itself. You may find more help on https://superuser.com/ with a question specifically on that topic. Good luck!

Comment: It depends on where `program.exe` expects input; is it at handle `0` (_STDIN_), or is it at the console?